# IF AND OR in Excel PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

So I am trying to create a custom column C that says if column "County" is blank AND Column "City" is NOT any of W, X, Y OR Z then print "Hello" in Column C. How do I do this? I am having trouble incorporating the is NOT part. This is what I have so far. How can I fix this?

if [County]="Blank" and [City] ="X" or [City] ="Y"or [City] ="Z" then "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

```
if [County] = null and List.Contains({"W","X","Y","Z"} ,[City]) = false then "Hello" else null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my starting point:

[image]

Go into "Conditional Column" and enter the following:

[image]

If you look into the "Advanced Editor", you have the following M code:

```
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Country", type text}, {"City", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Noup", each if [Country] = null or [City] = "W" or [City] = "X" or [City] = "Y" or [City] = "Z" then null else "Hello")
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

I am adding to my answer that the answer from Chris is a more elegant.